# Ubuntu keeps crashing/rebooting itself at same hour

Tags: server, 22.04, shutdown, reboot

My Ubuntu server with gnome installed keeps rebooting or crashing (almost everyday) at the same hour.

The server is used as headless server with GNOME installed to run some scripts and check data directly on the server, as well as work with some IDE. To do this, a dummy HDMI plug is on with caffeine to keep the screen preventing to go sleep, as I thought that the reboot issue was something related to this.

I've tried holding kernel updates (where seems to be the issue when I check `last reboot`)

```
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Fri Sep  2 05:04   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Wed Aug 31 05:03   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Tue Aug 30 17:29   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Tue Aug 30 05:03 - 17:29  (12:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Mon Aug 29 05:03 - 17:29 (1+12:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Sun Aug 28 05:03 - 17:29 (2+12:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Fri Aug 26 05:03 - 17:29 (4+12:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Sun Aug 21 05:03 - 17:29 (9+12:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Sat Aug 20 05:03 - 17:29 (10+12:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-46-generi Tue Aug 16 09:07 - 17:29 (14+08:21)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-43-generi Tue Aug 16 05:03 - 09:07  (04:03)
```

But the thing is the kernel is not updating anymore and the server keeps crashing.

When I ask `who -b`

```
system boot  2022-09-02 05:04
```

I've also checked for some cronjobs and the system doesn't have any, so I checked `systemctl list-timers --all`

```
               LEFT         LAST                         PASSED            UNIT                           ACTIVATES                       
 10:31:17 CEST 53min left   Sun 2022-09-04 09:30:35 CEST 6min ago          anacron.timer                  anacron.service
 12:46:58 CEST 3h 9min left Sun 2022-09-04 06:02:10 CEST 3h 35min ago      ua-timer.timer                 ua-timer.service
 15:58:24 CEST 6h left      Sat 2022-09-03 23:15:35 CEST 10h ago           motd-news.timer                motd-news.service
 19:15:17 CEST 9h left      Sun 2022-09-04 06:33:02 CEST 3h 4min ago       fwupd-refresh.timer            fwupd-refresh.service
 23:00:09 CEST 13h left     Sun 2022-09-04 07:52:02 CEST 1h 45min ago      apt-daily.timer                apt-daily.service
 00:00:00 CEST 14h left     n/a                          n/a               dpkg-db-backup.timer           dpkg-db-backup.service
 00:00:00 CEST 14h left     Sun 2022-09-04 00:00:03 CEST 9h ago            logrotate.timer                logrotate.service
 00:37:51 CEST 15h left     Mon 2022-08-29 00:19:21 CEST 6 days ago        fstrim.timer                   fstrim.service
 05:08:48 CEST 19h left     Sun 2022-09-04 05:08:48 CEST 4h 28min ago      update-notifier-download.timer update-notifier-download.service
 05:14:32 CEST 19h left     Sun 2022-09-04 00:36:41 CEST 9h ago            man-db.timer                   man-db.service
 05:18:33 CEST 19h left     Sun 2022-09-04 05:18:33 CEST 4h 19min ago      systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer   systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
 06:08:19 CEST 20h left     Sun 2022-09-04 06:08:02 CEST 3h 29min ago      apt-daily-upgrade.timer        apt-daily-upgrade.service
 20:01:12 CEST 4 days left  Mon 2022-08-22 01:40:48 CEST 1 week 6 days ago update-notifier-motd.timer     update-notifier-motd.service
 03:10:03 CEST 6 days left  Sun 2022-09-04 03:10:31 CEST 6h ago            e2scrub_all.timer              e2scrub_all.service
               n/a          n/a                          n/a               apport-autoreport.timer        apport-autoreport.service
               n/a          n/a                          n/a               snapd.snap-repair.timer        snapd.snap-repair.service
```

I don't see anything odd at the time of the reboots.

I'm desperate with this issue and I'm beginning to think about a faulty component, any help would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: If your logs show the system carefully terminating services and shutting down before rebooting, then it has a software cause. If your logs show the system rebooting without terminating services and shutting down, then it has a hardware cause.

Comment: Running out of memory perhaps?

Comment: @user535733 how can I check if the services are shutting down before rebooting?

Comment: @nobody I've checked that as well and my scripts are all very light and takes not that much memory, although I've 32GB of RAM

Comment: No one? System reboots almost everyday at same hour... can't be a hardware issue